# Inline list fluid horizontal items, expand extend items when in next line (min-width reached)

Tags: html, css, html-lists, fluid-layout

I have variable items in a list, and I want to extend them to 100% for reach the max space available (in a fluid column).

```
<------------------100%----------------->
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|    li   |   li    |    li   |   li    |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
```

on browser resize:

```
<--------------100%--------------->
|-----------|----------|----------|
|     li    |    li    |    li    |
|-----------|----------|----------|
|     li    |
|-----------|
```

Actually when resize browser:

```
<------------------100%-------------->
|---------|---------|---------|
|    li   |   li    |    li   |
|---------|---------|---------|
|    li   |
|---------|
```

All items have min-width 220px and I want to auto expand items when reached the min-width.

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
  ```css
  ul {text-align:justify;border:1px solid #ccc;width:100%;overflow:hidden}
  ul li {float:left;min-width:220px}
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
       <li>3</li>
       <li>4</li>
       <li>5</li>
       <li>6</li>
  </ul>
  ```

Comment: No. Not even flexbox can do that.

Comment: This is the result I would achieve, try to resize browser and see product section how it resize: http://www.overstock.com/Bedding-Bath/Towels/4529/cat.html?products=7480104&TID=BEDRDSP_BATHTOWELS